# Getting NuGet compile error only on specific branch - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I'm getting 3 types of errors when trying to build the project from a specific branch.

In the others branchs it works properly.

These are the problems:

1- `The command ""D:\Web\Hom\.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "D:\Web\Hom\ServiceClient\packages.config" -source "" -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "D:\Web\Hom\ "" exited with code 1.`

2- `Unable to find version '1.0.4632' of package 'AppFabric'.`

3- `NuGet Package restore failed for project Web.ServiceClient: Unable to find version '1.0.4632' of package 'AppFabric'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'AppFabric.1.0.4632' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'AppFabric.1.0.4632' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'`

Comment: Any update for this issue? Could you get useful information from Leo`s suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

NuGet will restore packages to the packages directory based on the packages.config file. Please compare the packages.config in specific branch with others branches, the package “AppFabric” element exists in the specific branch. So the NuGet would download the “AppFabric” package from the package Sources before project compiled.

According to the error messages, the “AppFabric” package has not been published to the NuGet server, NuGet could not download it from the NuGet server. You can according to the following methods to resolve this problem:

(1) Download the “AppFabric” package, [Creating a local NuGet repository](https://codurance.com/2015/05/04/creating-a-local-nuget-repository/), add this package to the repository.

(2) Download the “AppFabric” package, publish this package to the NuGet server before the project compiled.

Note that: You need to use "Update-Package -reinstall" command  in Package Manager Console force reinstall the package references and content files into project after restore successfully.